# Way to dynamic creating/modifying style with databinding

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding, styles, controltemplate

I have a `DataGrid`, which is bound to a `DataTable` object.  The user can press a special button, which will dynamically add new columns to this `DataTable` object. The `AutoGenerateFields` property in my `DataGrid` is set to false, because each column in this is styled column with a `DataTemplate` (each cell contains several `TextBlock`s).

I wrote the following style for my `DataGrid`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}" x:Key="YPStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                    <Grid Margin="4" Visibility="{Binding Path=DataItem.YPURL, Converter={StaticResource MyVisiblityConverter}}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
                                           FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="{Binding Path=DataItem.LYP}" x:Name="c"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                           Foreground="{Binding Path=DataItem.RYP, Converter={StaticResource MyColorConverter}}"
                                           Text="{Binding Path=DataItem.RYP}"
                                           Margin="3, 0, 0, 0"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            Margin="8, 0, 0, 0">
                            <Image Source="../icons/icon_url.gif"
                                           Cursor="Hand"/>
                            <Label Content="url"
                                           Foreground="Blue"
                                           Cursor="Hand"
                                           ToolTip="{Binding Path=DataItem.YPU}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You can see, that the `TextBlock`s are bound to some columns in `DataTable: DataItem.LYP, DataItem.YPU`.

The problem is finding a dynamic way to set that binding. When the user adds new columns to a bound `DataTable` object, I creates a new column in my `DataGrid` with this style. But how can I dynamically set different values for `Text` properties for my `TextBlock` in this style?

For example, first column in my `DataGrid` is bound to Column_1, Column_2, Column_3 in `DataTable`. When the user presses "Add new column", program creates 3 new columns in the `DataTable` object with names "Column_4", "Column5", Column 6" and creates new column in the `DataGrid` with this style. But how can I set binding for second column to new columns in the `DataTable`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use style wich was creating in code behind. It's working!
Thanks all.